# Query to fetch row corresponding to Max value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

there is a table time_periods with columns

```
time_period    START_DATE    PAY_DATE
1          01-DEC-2014     02-DEC-2014
1          12-NOV-2014     01-DEC-2014
```

PEOPLE_TABLE WITH COLUMNS

```
TIME_PERIOD   EMP_NUM  emp_name
1               101    xyz
```

I have created a  query :

```
select pt.emp_name,
max(tp.start_date),
tp.pay_date
from time_periods tp,
people_table pt
where tp.time_period=pt.time_period
group by pt.emp_name,tp.pay_date
```

but this is returning

```
emp_name    START_DATE    PAY_DATE
xyz          01-DEC-2014   02-DEC-2014
xyz          12-NOV-2014     01-DEC-2014
```

But this is returning two rows.... what i need is just one row which has max(start_date) and pay_date corresponding to that. that is :

```
emp_name    START_DATE    PAY_DATE
xyz          01-DEC-2014   02-DEC-2014
```

Comment: Basically another dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110512/get-latest-record-for-each-id/27110597#27110597

Comment: try removing the `group by` line, or remove the `tp.pay_date` part of it, depending on your intent. Otherwise, you should get a different record for each pay date for each user.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can use analytic functions for this:

```
select emp_name, max_start_date, pay_date
from (
    select pt.emp_name, 
           tp.start_date,
           tp.pay_date,
           rank() over(partition by pt.emp_name 
                       order by tp.start_date desc) rw,
    from time_periods tp, people_table pt
    where tp.time_period=pt.time_period
) where rw = 1;
```

**RANK()** may give you several rows for the same `emp_name` (if they all have the same `start_date`)

You can use **ROW_NUMBER()** instead of **RANK()** if you need only one row for each `emp_name`

Comment: check that op groups by `pt.emp_name,tp.pay_date`, i suggest partition by `pt.emp_name,tp.pay_date`

Comment: @Aramillo Thanks for your comment, but "... this is returning two rows.... what i need is just one row which has max(start_date) and pay_date corresponding to that"

Comment: this query is running since a long time... no ouput

Comment: ohh, yes, i see. You're rigth then.:)